# Securing a File Download with Http referrer

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to understand if this will be enough to secure a file download in a application with

- jquery/MVC4 - Jquery invokes the download (using filedownload plugin https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload)
- MVC4 action is called for download (validates the request)
- Calls a web api2 - rest for download.(where we have user validations in place)

  1. We have SSO in place (can this be easily spoofed)
  2. We are using session cookies to send down the file id's (guids).
  3. We are checking for the Request.UrlReferrer in the download to see if this is set or not to see if this is a direct link request or not (can this be easily spoofed?)
  4. Our file download expired in 10 mins.

Can someone drop some in-sight if this will be enough to ensure the safe download

Comment: Request.UrlReferrer can also be easily spoofed.